# Steps to integrate Cesium.js with Mapguide Opensource

Tags: cartography, rest, mapguide, cesium, mapguide-maestro

I render map in php mapviewer with mapguide opensource and postgresql/postgis and edit with mapguide maestro.
What would be steps to integrate cesium.js?

Comment: This question seems very broad, maybe start with the [Getting Started Guide](http://cesiumjs.org/2013/04/12/Cesium-up-and-running/).

Answer (score 1):

Use map guide rest to stream czml to cesiumjs

http://www.mapguide.ca/foss4gna2015/foss4g_NA_2015_mapguide_cesium.pdf

http://themapguyde.blogspot.com/2014/09/announcing-mapguide-rest-010.html